# linux <-> windows network (ethernet) connectivity over usb

Tags: windows, linux, networking, usb, ethernet

**problem:**
I have a linux box that i want to use as firewall for my Windows workstation. it has only one ethernet that is needed for the switch, but no pci expansion slots.
So the only option to connect another machine to this one is through a USB cable, and the box to the net through the standard cat5 cable.

**what is needed:**
while a usbnet driver is available for linux to push ethernet over usb, i dont know about windows.
I found on wikipedia that there's a driver for winxp, called *bahia network driver*, but it's has been released in 2003.

**the question:**
Is there a driver that is more recent and win-7 compatible?

**update**: i found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501313/connect-two-computers-via-usb

it seems it is fairly easy to link linux <-> linux over usb using the ethernet network protocol, but it does not say anything related to win <-> linux

Comment: Anything more recent to do what? What device are you trying to find a driver for?

Comment: I am looking for a virtual ethernet driver to push the ethernet through a standard usb cable

Comment: What would you connect the USB cable *to*? If you don't have a device, there's nothing for the driver to drive.

Comment: I want to connect 2 machines via ethernet over a usb cable. I thought it was clear enough in my explanation..
And i think i still need a driver, just like the tap driver is required for virtual ethernet interfaces

Comment: Then you need two USB Ethernet adapters. You'll need drivers for the particular USB Ethernet adapters you choose.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to assign two (or more) IP addresses to a single network card (NIC) on a Linux computer.  One example of how to set it up is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/571575/connect-to-two-lan-networks-with-a-single-card).  Another explanation is [here](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-assign-multiple-ip-addresses-to-one-network-interface-on-centos.html).  I have used this solution as well as using the USB Ethernet adapter solution.