# Using two IP addresses running at the same time with one NIC

Tags: networking, ip

does anyone know how to setup a machine that can both run two IP addresses at the same time.. im using Win7 Pro 32-bit, i've read some thread over the net, the fastest way to do this is to have a 2nd NIC, but is there a way to like "simulate" two LAN cards? think of it as having a VM Ware only thing is that your only replacating the NIC.

Anyone knows this please do reply..

Comment: If you are not using DHCP for one of the IPs then [this answer will work on win7](http://superuser.com/questions/571575/connect-to-two-lan-networks-with-a-single-card/571586#571586)

Comment: What addresses do you want to set? Why/what for? (If you need to ask how to do it, I doubt you have a good reason to do it.)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Staus of your `Local Area Connection`  Click `Properties`, Select `Internet Protocol Version 4` then `Advanced` and click the button `Add` under `IP addresses`.

You can add a second network there, you can also add a second gateway below.

Comment: done that but i can't seem to have them run on parallel.. one is disabled while the other is running and vice versa

Comment: Are they on the same subnet?

Comment: yes 255.255 something..

Comment: No, that's the subnet mask. What I'm asking is if you have two IP addresses in the same subnet. If your subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 you have 255 addresses to use, so from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.254 (any number in that range is considered to be in the same subnet).

Comment: ohhh i see yes 192.24.1.1 and 192.24.1.2 thats my ips

Comment: Yeah, it's possible that windows won't run two of those together, as it needs special routing rules, to make sure that replies come from the same IP that was contacted..