# Assigning different IPs to apps without the use of VMs

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtual-machine, ip, routing

I'm trying to run multiple copies of a game in the same host but the game checks for your IP before letting you connect. So I'm looking for a way to get around that problem. I've rented VPNs and were using them on VMs. But after learning that there are ways to do it without VMs I am looking for some more information.

What is the correct way here? Should I look into proxies instead? Should I look into routing rules? I tried creating a TAP adapter, tried using ForceBindIP but I couldn't succeed.

edit: I'm on Windows 7

Comment: This question is closely related to the OS you are using. Could you add this information?

Comment: On Windows, ForceBindIP and the like seem to be the easiest way.

Comment: @mtak Added....

Comment: @grawity But ForceBindIP is for when you have multiple NICs. I can't actually figure out how to apply it to my situation..

Comment: @canberk: It's for when you have multiple IP addresses, whether they're assigned to one NIC or multiple is irrelevant. And a VPN connection _is_ usually a virtual NIC anyway. That said, your situation is still somewhat unclear. How exactly were you using the VMs before? Were you setting up one VPN connection inside each VM?

Comment: @grawity, Yes, for each app I was running a VM with Windows 7 inside and was connecting each one through a VPN. And the way I set up VPN connection it is not clear to me how to use ForceBindIP. I tried connecting a VPN (shown as WAN Miniport in Network Connections) and forcing apps to run on the main connection but it didn't work (As soon as I connect to a VPN, the forced app disconnects from internet). Even if it worked, I don't see how I can do it for more than 1 VPN connection.

Answer (score 1):

### Using multiple IP addresses

You can assign the host multiple IP addresses on the same network interface.
Here are some tutorials: [Connect to two LAN networks with a single card](https://superuser.com/questions/571575/connect-to-two-lan-networks-with-a-single-card) or [How to Quickly Add Multiple IP Addresses to Windows Servers](http://www.howtogeek.com/51741/how-to-quickly-add-multiple-ip-addresses-to-windows-servers/)

Next, you need to check that your host is reachable from the outside on all these addresses. You could use something simple like [iperf](https://iperf.fr/). Open an iperf server with a binding to one IP on your host, and see if it works. Do this for each IP separately.

Now you can use ForceBindIP to bind each instance of your game to one specific IP address.

### Using NAT

If you can not or do not have multiple public IPs, using a NAT setup might work. Here your public IP would be assigned to a router that does the NATing. The router would have a private network with the server and the server would have multiple IPs in this network (see above). Now you could assign different port forwadings to each server IP.

For that to work, your game must allow you to change the server port (at least on the client side).