# Is Internet Shared from PC can access the main network group?

Tags: networking

Is there technique or software can access after internet shared network into the main network. In other word I got internet from ISP LAN ip 192.168.1.1-255 then shared from my PC giving ip 192.168.137.1 if i connect 2nd network and can access the main network to do file sharing and printer sharing. or Can you tell me other solution. tks

Answer (score 0):

To allow file and printer sharing the networks should be visible. If you change the subnet mask to 255.255.0.0 the PC with the IP 192.168.137.1 should see the devices in the subnet 192.168.1.x

It depends of the subnet mask. If they are not in the same subnet you will need to configure a VPN or similar to allow visibility between devices.

Comment: both network the subnet 255.255.0.0 can I change?

Comment: if in both networks the mask is 255.255.0.0 then both networks are virtually the same. Try to ping from one network to the other and tell us.

Comment: unable to change subnet from shared PC it automatic change into ip 192.168.137.1 and subnet is 255.255.255.0

Comment: Follow [this instructions](http://superuser.com/questions/571575/connect-to-two-lan-networks-with-a-single-card) to configure multiple IP. Create one IP in each network.